# Bibtex doesn't compile with a new style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I'm trying to change my bibliographystyle from unsrt to nar. However, pdflatex, bibtex , 2x pdflatex(using Texmaker) always gives me the following Error:

`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.`
I tried to delete the bib and aux files, but it doesn't seem to work. I've got two *.bib files. One is created by Mendeley and one is created by me. This is an example of one of my entries:

```
@book{saleh,
  Author = {Bahaa E. A. Saleh and Malvin C. Teich},
  Title = {Fundamentals of Photonics (Wiley Series in Pure and Applied Optics)},
  Publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  Year = {1991},
  ISBN = {0471839655},
  URL = {http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Photonics-Series-Applied-Optics/dp/0471839655%3FSubscriptionId%3D0JYN1NVW651KCA56C102%26tag%3Dtechkie-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0471839655}
}
```

This is how I cite:

```
\cite{feyn}
```

It seems there are a lot of these questions, but all the proposed solutions don't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`? Doing so will direct `natbib` to create numeric-style citation callouts.

Comment: That did the trick thanks. If you want to I would accept it as the right answer.

Comment: I've just posted the comment as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [nar](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nar) bibliography style is meant to be used with *numeric-style* (as opposed to, say, authoryear-style) citations. Thus, be sure to load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`. (That package's default is to create authoryear-style citations.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{saleh,
  Author = {Bahaa E. A. Saleh and Malvin C. Teich},
  Title = {Fundamentals of Photonics (Wiley Series in Pure and Applied Optics)},
  Publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  Address  = {New York},
  Year = {1991},
  ISBN = {0471839655},
  URL = {http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Photonics-Series-Applied-Optics/dp/0471839655%3FSubscriptionId%3D0JYN1NVW651KCA56C102%26tag%3Dtechkie-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0471839655}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{nar}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{saleh}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```